# How to capture an Infrared signal pattern & frequency for later use?

Tags: java, android, infrared

I'm wanting to create an Android app that will send IR signals, but I don't know how to find the signal patterns or the frequencies from the original transmitter.

I purchased a small USB IR receiver (not Microsoft, but uses the Microsoft EHome drivers) and I can see the patterns from WinLIRC, but they are barely consistent, and trying to use any of them doesn't work on the receiver. I also am not sure what frequency to transmit on. I have my app sending back the signals and I can see them in LIRC, and they're accurate, but the receiver from the original remote doesn't respond to it.

How can I get the info from the original transmitter, accurately, without spending tons of money on something like an oscilloscope?

Comment: I guess an inexpensive Arduino Nano (Chinese clone) is your best friend.